# Are decimal types still needed with JavaScript's BigInt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, int, decimal

Most recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and Node have support to BigInt https://v8.dev/blog/bigint.

I read about it but I can't understand, is this just a normal 64-bit integer? I know that JavaScript doesn't have any Decimal type like C# or Java's BigDecimal, can the BigInt be used instead of these?

Comment: They're arbitrary-precision integers, not 64-bit integers. They're not directly usable as something like `BigDecimal` in Java. [Click on the link right there in the article you posted.](https://v8.dev/features/bigint)

Comment: @Pointy does an arbitrary-precision integer replaces the need for a "normal" integer type in JavaScript?

Comment: well that's a matter of opinion. There's plenty of JavaScript code in the world without a simple integer type.